# Parse Dashboard on Heroku : Unable to see Analytics and App Settings

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-dashboard

I have deployed a parse app on Heroku. I have also deployed Parse Dashboard (from [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard) repo) and configured it to show the already deployed apps. Now, when I open the Dashboard in heroku, I can see 'Core' and 'Push' tab as per the below screen shot:

[image]

However, I can't see the 'Analytics' tab (it was there when the app was hosted on Parse.com). Is there any way I can enable this tab in dashboard?

Comment: There is no analytics anymore

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue on parse-dashboard project about this: [issue #558](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/558)

it seems that the feature is awaiting for a new mantainer before it will be merged into a new version of the dasboard